# How to set image1 overlap image2 android

Tags: java, android, xml, image, bitmap

How to set image1 overlap image2

I want to set image1(by Drawable) overlap image2(by bitmap)

example

[image]

In the example above

icon play is image1 and picture is image2

I found slove is only image1 and image2 is by drawable

and If image2 is by bitmap ,I have no idea to set it

ps. sorry my english is not good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**file.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"           
            android:background="@drawable/bacground_pic"
          />

     <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="trues"
          />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

2. secondly you have to set Bitmap to second image with this

> ```
> ImageView image_1=(ImageView) findviewbyid(R.id.image_1);
> image_1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
> ```

Comment: why don't you replace image_1 with image_2 and swap there position in relativelayout.

Answer (score 0):

On ImageView object you can set a background image and as well as the ImageResource. Another way of doing this is RelativeLayout, place two ImageView overlapping each other.

Answer (score 0):

ImageView having extra properties to set extra [bitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)) or [icon](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageIcon(android.graphics.drawable.Icon)) or [drawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) other than normal Background in View properties,

So for your case, you can set Play icon as src(which will come on top of background and center) and Bitmap you can set as Background

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/video"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/msg_media_play_small_icon" >
        </ImageView>
```

and to set the Background Image, don't use `imageView.setImageBitmap`
use `imageView.setBackground`

```
imageview.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap));
```